# Keycloak : Angularjs app logout when ever i refresh the page?

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

I'm using `Keycloack` in my `angularjs` app for login and its working fine.
But after the login in the application when ever a user tries to do a page refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>) the application will logout and it will show the login page to the user.

Can someone please let me know what can be cause of this issue?

Comment: Can you check whether you have angular route in place??

Comment: Which keycloak adapter are you using?

Comment: @XtremeBiker javascript adapter i m using

Comment: @ramanathan I did not get your question ,is there any change required in routing file as well?

Comment: Yes..But before saying it i have to check your route file configuration in angular

Comment: @ramanathan Its not related to angular .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got where is the issue ,please find attached screen shot
[image]

So i checked the [Keyclock](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/server_admin/topics/authentication/flows.html) documentation and they wrote

> The next execution is a subflow called Forms. Since this subflow is
>   marked as alternative it will not be executed if the Cookie
>   authentication type passed. This subflow contains additional
>   authentication type that needs to be executed. The executions for this
>   subflow are loaded and the same processing logic occurs

So considering above documented statement i made changes in keyclock server as well and it worked

[image]